# Group several files needed to run a program into one executable

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, executable

There are times where I create small projects for personal use. Therefore I just extract the debug directory from my project and run the executable file whenever I need to use my application. How could I combine all this files:

[image]

into one executable. I know I can place that folder somewhere in my c drive and have a shortcut to the executable file. I am just curious to know how could this be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things are important to realize here:

1. You should never distribute the Debug version of an application. Always compile in "Release" mode for the final release of your application, the one you're going to let people use (even if those people are just you).

   There are many, *many* reasons to do this, but the most obvious one is that compiling in "Release" mode will enable both compile-time and run-time optimizations that allow your code to run significantly faster.
2. Only one of the files you've shown there is actually required to run your application, and that's the `.EXE` file itself. That's the only one you have to distribute. The rest of the files just provide debugging information and are used by Visual Studio. Since you probably won't need to debug the application once it's written, you don't need these files at all.

   In fact, the only time you need to distribute anything beyond the `.EXE` file is if you have `.DLL` library files that your app uses. They might be libraries that you created yourself from another project within the same solution, or they might be libraries that someone else wrote and you're using to provide some functionality to your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try copying just the exe file to a separate directory and run the exe? The other 3 files listed in your screenshot are not needed for your application to run.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to combine the whole folder, you could just move the one file 'ConsoleApplication26.exe' to wherever you care to and run it happily on its own. The other files just contain information that are used when you debug the program in the Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you only need the .exe file, since the rest contains debug information etc.

But generally speaking dll files can be places in the global assembly cache (or GAC). [MSDN article on the GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) This should - as mentioned in the comments - be handled by an installer, but is the way to avoid leaving dll's in the program folder. As Cody mentions it will in general be better to leave them in the program folder.

If you have resources like images or text files these can be embedded inside the executable by setting them as embedded resources in Visual Studio.

They are then accessible as streams inside the executing assembly (`this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name)` where name is the default namespace "." filename. The method GetManifestResourceNames can be consulted if you want to learn the names of the embedded resources.

But including resources also means that you will have to rewrite some of the resource loading to use the resource streams, so it requires some extra work.

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Generally speaking, you should **not** register DLLs in the GAC. Your analysis is in *direct contradiction* with the MSDN article that you cite. And even more importantly, never try to register DLLs in the GAC yourself manually. Always create an installer that does this for you when it's necessary.

Comment: Hey - Sorry I will rephrase, it was not meant as a recommendation but as a way to obtain the desired effect in the question. Personally I don't register and it is wrong. Thanks for clearifying. My aim was to lead attention to the embedded resources.

Comment: Okay, but it's still not the way to achieve the desired effect. What the question talks about is Xcopy deployment, long touted as one of the primary advantages of code targeting the .NET Framework. It's not necessary to install *any* dependencies in the GAC for this to work. They should simply sit in the folder with your application, or be merged into a single assembly using something like ILMerge if *absolutely necessary*. In fact, registering the dependency assemblies in the GAC means you *can't* use Xcopy deployment, as that same MSDN article indicates.

Comment: I completely agree and I have never installed a dll in GAC for deployment purposes since it has always ment troubles when redeploying. But I will just point to your comments about the GAC since they are definately better than mine :)

Comment: DLLs are *supposed* to be in the program folder. Registering them globally leads in large part to the situation colloquially known as "DLL Hell" that the phenomenon of .NET and managed code was supposed to solve for good. It's not been entirely successful, but keeping dependencies *local* has certainly helped a lot. Taking a strictly local dependency, and elevating it to a global one is just **bad advice**.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. There's a lot of confusion about this. I'm not sure where it comes from. Even unmanaged developers have been told for years not to create global dependencies when a local one would do.